# CASE statement with Absolute Values

Tags: sql, t-sql

The CASE statement doesn't seem to be catching a record with a negative value even though I am using the ABS() function on the expression. The record in question is the one with the value of -1.52 which should fall in the range of the case statement "

```
WHEN ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) >1*@SD
                     AND ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) <=2*@SD
                     THEN 'Recommend Review'
```

"

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance! (sorry about the formatting on the expected results)

Script to create table containing sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample_Data](
    [ID] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [Actual_Hours] [decimal](38, 2) NULL,
    [Standard_Hours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [DifferenceHours] [decimal](38, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'490412', CAST(1.22 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(0.30 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'491712', CAST(1.36 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(0.44 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'493822', CAST(1.96 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(1.04 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'496762', CAST(1.51 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(1.84 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(-0.33 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'497082', CAST(2.72 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(1.80 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'497092', CAST(1.45 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(0.53 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'497162', CAST(2.06 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(1.14 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'498002', CAST(2.03 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(1.11 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'498632', CAST(0.89 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(-0.03 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'499162', CAST(0.79 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(1.84 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(-1.05 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Sample_Data] ([ID], [Actual_Hours], [Standard_Hours], [DifferenceHours]) VALUES (N'499582', CAST(1.19 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.92 AS Decimal(10, 2)), CAST(0.27 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
```

**Code in question:**

I am struggling with the formatting on stack exchange. When I paste my code in it jacks up line breaks and strips out 'some' asterisks. I have no idea why. I posted the code here while I try to sort it out. Interestingly enough it seemed to have no trouble with the code to create the table containing the sample data.

https://codedump.io/share/7ISZ7p8qrXvu/1

---

FROM Sample_Data

My Expected result:

```
ID     | Actual_Hours | Standard_Hours | DifferenceHours | Deviation | Recommendation
490412 | 1.22        | 0.92            | 0.30           | -0.17 |
491712 | 1.36        | 0.92            | 0.44           | -0.03 |
493822 | 1.96        | 0.92            | 1.04           | 0.57  | 
496762 | 1.51        | 1.84            |-0.33 | -0.80   |
497082 | 2.72        | 0.92            | 1.80 | 1.33    |   Recommend Review
497092 | 1.45        | 0.92            | 0.53 | 0.06    |
497162 | 2.06        | 0.92            | 1.14 | 0.67    | 
498002 | 2.03        | 0.92            | 1.11 | 0.64    |
498632 | 0.89        | 0.92            |-0.03 | -0.50   | 
499162 | 0.79        | 1.84            | -1.05| -1.52   | RecommendReview <- 
499582 | 1.19        | 0.92            | 0.27 | -0.20   |
```

Comment: Did something get stripped out of your code when you copy and paste? I get errors at Standard_Hours)100>25

Comment: one sec, ill check. thanks for looking at this by the way

Comment: yes, something got jacked with the copy & paste, trying to fix it now

Comment: I posted a link to the code - the formatting is giving me fits here..

Comment: I found your issue, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using this specific row value where Actual_Hours= .79 and Standard_Hours = 1.84 we evaluate the math and we get...

```
WHEN ((Actual_Hours - Standard_Hours)/Standard_Hours)* 100>25 THEN
    CASE ...
    ELSE ''
ELSE ''
```

Inputting the data into the calculation:

```
((.79 - 1.84)/1.84) * 100
```

Simplifying:

```
(-.57) * 100
-57
```

Does not evaluate to >25 since this value is negative. Thus, your FIRST CASE is not true, and evaluates to ELSE (your blank string ''). You will notice the same problem on row 4 and 9 also.

To solve, you maybe (probably?) want to wrap your first CASE in an ABS as well. But that may depend on your business logic.

And for full disclosure on how I tested, I added these two columns to your query:

```
DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff AS CaseTestResult,
((Actual_Hours - Standard_Hours)/Standard_Hours)* 100 AS HoursCalc
```

This allowed me to compare the CASE statements to the results and work back to the solution.

Comment: That helps a lot! - thank you very much. The extra columns to do a visual check is a great idea. I'll definitely be using that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the problem is not if your case statement but the Standard Deviation.

The SD is 0.75 then 2 * 0.75 = 1.50 not 1.52

Try it:

```
SELECT *        
    , DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff AS 'Deviation'    
    , CASE                                                
        WHEN ((Actual_Hours - Standard_Hours)/Standard_Hours)*100>25
            THEN          
                CASE 
                    WHEN ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff)<=1*@SD
                    THEN ''

                    WHEN ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) >1*@SD
                    AND ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) <=2*@SD
                    THEN 'Recommend Review'

                    WHEN ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) > 2*@SD
                    THEN 'Strongly Recommend Review'
                ELSE ''
                END
        ELSE ''
        END AS 'Recommendation'
        ,ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) [ABS(DifferenceHours - @Mean_Diff) ]
        , 1*@SD [1*@SD] 
        , 2.*@SD [2*@SD]
```

FROM Sample_Data

Comment: 1.52 > 1.50 which is (2*.75)... so the result would be 'Strongly Recommend Review', but it never gets to that point. The problem is not with the ABS calculations, but the first CASE

Comment: Try this, change the last ELSE '' to ELSE 'TEST' and run the statement and see what you get for results.